# asp.net forms authentication timing out after 1 minute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 with the Authorize attribute, but it keeps kicking me to the logon page after 1 minute, but even though my expiration is set to a very high value, it times out quickly. I check the cookie in my browser and its still there and not set to expire until about a month later, and it's set to be persistent, so I'm not sure why it keeps booting me. It only happens on my published location, locally it works just fine.

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(username, true, 500000);
var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
```

Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="7200" slidingExpiration="false"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: What are the settings for Session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the worker process is recycled meantime, Where do you store the sessions?

Making your sessions stored out of process may helps.

Comment: What Jani said - it sounds like the resources on your server are being continuously recycled, which flushes all of the session stores server-side. See if setting your sessions out-of-process will resolve the issue.

Comment: I contacted my host and they upped my private memory limit and virtual memory limit on my app pool, and that has now fixed the issue. Seems odd it would of existed as aside from authentication I wasn't storing anything at all in the session. Either way, working now, thanks.